# authorize.net production certificate upgrades

Tags: ssl, ssl-certificate, authorize.net, sha

I have a website that integrates with authorize.net and received a notice that they are upgrading their certificates so that they are signed using Security Hash Algorithm 2 (SHA-2). Specifically, that their API services will use EnTrust’s SHA-256, 2048-bit certificate.

It goes on: "Please contact your solution provider and web hosting company to ensure your solution has these certificates installed and is capable of using them to secure your connection to Authorize.Net. "

When users connect to the payment pages on my site, they are on a secure connection (DigiCert SHA-256 certificate), but I'm not sure if that means that my site's connection to api.authorize.net is similarly secured.

Sorry for asking what is probably a very dumb question, but how can I find out if this change will require any re-coding on my end, and how can I check that my site's certificate is going to work?

Thanks so much for your help!

Answer (score 0):

I also got the notice from authorize.net, but fortunately for me our hosting site's admins took care of it.  I got a similar notice from PayPal, which is also upgrading their certificates for SHA-256 compliance. In researching that one I came across this related Stack Overflow question: [How can I tell if my paypal certificate is SHA-256? - PayPal service upgrades](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32609093/how-can-i-tell-if-my-paypal-certificate-is-sha-256-paypal-service-upgrades).

One answer links to this [github gist](https://gist.github.com/robglas/3ef9582c6292470a1743) which uses openssl and awk to check the installed certs. If you run it and see the certs that authorize.net has upgraded too listed, that should tell you your server will work.  This is a assuming you're on a Linux server.  Disclaimer: I'm no expert on dealing with SSL and servers - I'm chiming in only because no one else has.