# How can I tell if my paypal certificate is SHA-256? - PayPal service upgrades

Tags: paypal, openssl, ssl-certificate, paypal-ipn

I use IPN endpoints and have received emails from paypal saying PayPal is upgrading the certificate for www.paypal.com to SHA-256.

I just want to make sure my certificate will keep working.

I have tried checking on https://shaaaaaaaaaaaaa.com, https://shachecker.com, www.sslshopper.com/ssl-checker.html but none will check it (I assume they all require an https site, which mine isn't?).

I have tried a transaction though the sandbox and this works fine.

I have run `openssl s_client -connect www.sandbox.paypal.com:443 -showcerts -CApath /etc/ssl/certs/` on my ubuntu server and see a lot of information ending in `Verify return code: 0 (ok)` it then just hangs. Does that mean there is a problem? What am I looking for in this information?

(If I run the same for www.paypal.com it pauses on the `Verify` line, then says `closed`)

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask. Also see [Where do I post questions about Dev Ops?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/134306).

Comment: This is where the paypal developer page take you. It says Visit StackOverflow to check out our PayPal forum with a link to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/paypal. I thought it was a little odd, but couldn't see any alternative!

Answer (score 0):

Here are the details for the Certificate Upgrade:
[Merchant Response Guide](https://www.paypal-knowledge.com/resources/sites/PAYPAL/content/live/FAQ/1000/FAQ1766/en_US/2015%20Merchant%20Security%20System%20Upgrade%20Guide%20%28U.S.%20English%29.pdf)
[Certificate FAQ](https://www.paypal-knowledge.com/infocenter/index?page=content&id=FAQ1766&expand=true&locale=en_US)
This comes from the Merchant Response Guide:

> **Our Response:** 
>     In accordance with industry standards, PayPal will no longer accept secure 
>   connections to the API/IPN endpoints that are expecting our Certificate/trust chain to be signed by the G2 Root Certificate. Only 
>   secure connection requests that are expecting our certificate/trust chain to be signed by the G5 Root Certificate will result in successful secure 
>   connections.

Here is how to check your Certificate through Linux. This comes from GitHub: 
[How to Check All Certificates through Linux](https://gist.github.com/robglas/3ef9582c6292470a1743)

```
#!/bin/bash

echo "All certificates in ca-certificates.crt, listed by subject:"
awk -v cmd='openssl x509 -noout -subject' '/BEGIN/{close(cmd)};{print | cmd}' < /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt

echo "All certificates in ca-certificates.crt, listed by subject, check for presence of VeriSign's 'Class 3 Public Primary - G5':"
awk -v cmd='openssl x509 -noout -subject' '/BEGIN/{close(cmd)};{print | cmd}' < /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt | grep "G5"
```

Comment: Thanks for that. Response to the awk is `subject= /C=US/O=VeriSign, Inc./OU=VeriSign Trust Network/OU=(c) 2006 VeriSign, Inc. - For authorized use only/CN=VeriSign Class 3 Public Primary Certification Authority - G5`  Does that mean its ok?

Comment: yes, G5 - is the trusted Certificate. If this is what you are using then you are compliant.