# Email about IPN certificate upgrade: Is it legit?

Tags: paypal, paypal-ipn

A few days ago, I received the following email from address paypal@paypal.com and with subject "IMMEDIATE ATTENTION REQUIRED: PayPal service upgrades.".

I have reason to believe it is a phishing attempt. Please find my notes in the end and try to justify why I'm right or wrong.

The only part of the mail that I removed was my name in the third line.

> PayPal service upgrades.
>
> ,
>
> As we have previously communicated to you, PayPal is upgrading the
>
> certificate for www.paypal.com to SHA-256. This endpoint is also used
>   by merchants using the Instant Payment Notification (IPN) product.
>
> This upgrade is scheduled for 9/30/2015; however, we may need to
>   change this date on short notice to you to align to the industry
>   security standard.
>
> You’re receiving this notification because you’ve been identified as a
>   merchant who has used IPN endpoints within the past year. If you have
>   not made the necessary changes, we urge you to do so right away to
>   avoid a disruption of your service!
>
> Because these changes are technical in nature, we advise that you
>   consult with your individuals responsible for your PayPal integration.
>   They will be able to identify what, if any, changes are needed. Please
>   share this email and the hyperlinks below with your technical contact
>   for evaluation.
>
> Testing in the Sandbox is one of the best ways to make sure your
>   integration works. Sandbox endpoints have been upgraded to accept
>   secure connections by the SHA-256 Certificates.
>
> Full technical details can be found in our [Merchant Security System
>   Upgrade Guide](https://www.paypal-knowledge.com/resources/sites/PAYPAL/content/live/FAQ/1000/FAQ1766/en_US/2015%20Merchant%20Security%20System%20Upgrade%20Guide%20%28U.S.%20English%29.pdf). In addition, our [2015-2016 SSL Certificate Change
>   microsite](https://www.paypal-knowledge.com/infocenter/index?page=content&id=FAQ1766&expand=true&locale=en_US) contains a schedule of our service upgrade plan.
>
> Thanks for your patience as we continue to improve our services.
>
> Please do not reply to this email. We are unable to respond to
>   inquiries sent to this address. For immediate answers to your
>   questions, visit our Help Center by clicking "Help" on any PayPal
>   page. Copyright © 2014 PayPal. All rights reserved. PayPal (Europe)
>   S.á r.l. et Cie, S.C.A., Société en Commandite par Actions. Registered
>   office: 22-24 Boulevard Royal, L-2449, Luxembourg, R.C.S. Luxembourg B
>   118 349.

Here's why I think it's fake:

1. They just address the customer by name, no "Dear" etc.
2. Copyright 2014? strange...
3. The phrase "we may need to change this date on short notice to you to align to the industry security standard" has a minor mistake (IMO, although I'm not a native English speaker) and doesn't sound like a company's policy. Talking about *maybe* changing a date is not professional.
4. The subject... come on, caps?
5. The links are to a strange domain, the certificate of which is issued by a different company than paypal.com's. One serves a pdf.

I think it's a pretty elaborate phishing attempt, but it strikes me that in online discussions about it (dating back many months), representatives of various companies treat it as legit.

So, am I missing something?

Comment: received the same email looks legit to me.

Comment: The maintenance is posted on paypal-notify.com
https://www.paypal-notify.com/eventnotification/event_details?eventId=6715  also paypal-knowledge.com is the FAQ system for paypal-techsupport.com

Comment: For anything that might look like phishing you can check with  spoof@paypal.com

https://www.paypal.com/us/webapps/helpcenter/helphub/article/?solutionId=FAQ2331

Comment: Thanks @randstraw, it took them 10 days but they finally confirmed it's legit. This was just to verify the approved answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes that is a Legitimate email from PayPal.

For additional details, see this recent Stack Question:

[How can I tell if my paypal certificate is SHA-256?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32609093/how-can-i-tell-if-my-paypal-certificate-is-sha-256-paypal-service-upgrades)

The [PayPal Merchant Technical Support](https://www.paypal-techsupport.com/) Site has additional information on the Certificate Upgrade and how to test your server.

Also if you ever wonder if an email is from PayPal you can forward the email to Spoof@paypal.com or the new email Review@paypal.com.